# Where can I read about the Princelings in depth?

Tags: communism, china

I'm looking for a comprehensive study of the Chinese [Princelings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princelings). Is there a book or a thorough article (or a series of articles) in which I could find this? It would be best if the text were pleasant to read, but the most important thing for me is that it be comprehensive. It doesn't have to attempt to be objective.

Comment: The Economist often does profiles of the Princelings in their China section\

Comment: @AffableGeek Thank you. I'll definitely have to take a look. It's not exactly the perfect solution for me, but it could be good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be quite some academic writing about the subject, but not much of it is readily available and much of it quickly digresses into sidetrack subjects. I did find two that might be interesting to read..

D. Barboza, S. LaFraniere (2012) Princelings' in China Use Family Ties to Gain Riches. [available here](http://www.bannedthought.org/China/Capitalism-Imperialism/2012/PrincelingsGainRiches-120517.pdf)

Hedrick‐Wong, Y. (2006). The three paths: Meeting leadership challenges in China and India. Leadership in Action, 26(5), 3-6. [available here](http://uwww.ccl.org/leadership/pdf/publications/lia/lia26_5Paths.pdf)